# What's better to use: ' or "

Tags: php

What is better to use in PHP?
' or "? for something like this:

```
<?=$json["response"]["players"][0]["personaname"];?>
```

And this:

```
$steamid = "";
```

Comment: I really have good experience with this rule of thumb: for literal strings used as technical identifiers use a single quote, for human readable text phrases use double quotes.

Comment: Okay, that's à nice way to remember that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Better" really depends on your use cases. In both your example, the single quote is better for the perfomance because you have no $variable interpolation needed.

Otherwise "better" may be a question of style (and a little of performance).

Read the documentation for more : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I'll read the documentation, thank you.

Comment: In modern versions of PHP there is practically no difference in performance anymore between single and double quotes.

Comment: Yes I agree. But that's still the reason no to use double quotes everywhere I think. By the way, if you *really* want performance improvements, use the most modern php engine, switch language, or create a C php extension. Or learn how to reduce algorithm complexity. There are always many ways for improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Better? Well, let's just say that an empty string with single quotes is the most basic string literal you can use. In your example shown, I would use single quoted strings for array elements and the empty string. PHP will know that the string literal is only a string literal, and that nothing else needs to be "interpolated." Better? Who knows.

One place to use "" is with escape sequences such as "\n" .

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer